# Core Data input fetches into labels

Tags: core-data

I want to store data from a text field. And then use this data to populate the text in a label inside a view controller. Is this possible? Ive messed around with it, but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts? Here are my two methods...

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSManagedObject *noteEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
[noteEntry setValue:_notesField.text forKey:@"notes"];

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![coreDataStack.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}




[coreDataStack saveContext];


}
```

Here is my view did load method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notes"];
Notes *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

_outputLabel.text = entry.notes;

}
```

Comment: It's certainly possible. What's not clear from your question is how you intend to get the managed object. CoreData fetch requests aren't intended to fetch a single, particular object. They match all objects in the store that match your given criteria. This is why it's common to use core data to populate a list view using a NSFetchedResultsController, and have the user choose a particular model object using that (ala the Master-Detail template).

Comment: @quellish what would be the best way to get this single object? I want a persistent storage. I guess i just figured core data.

Comment: Have you considered UIDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the `saveButton:` method seems OK. But your code in the `viewDidLoad` method seems wrong. Are you trying to do the following?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    //First way to init your fetchRequest:
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notes"];

    //Second way to init your fetchRequest:
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //Having a NSEntityDescription object can be usefull if you need to group your data, for example

    //Set some predicates, if necessary
    //Set some sortdescriptors, if necessary

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *resultsArray = [coreDataStack executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", resultsArray);
    _outputLabel.text = [[resultsArray firstObject] notes]; //if your array can only have one object
}
```

The NSLog will give you the structure of your fetch array (I can't guess it). You will then be able to set `_outputLabel.text`.

Comment: its seems i left out the NSArray. In my data model, i have one entity , Notes, with one attribute, note. Do i need to call [request setEntity:@"Notes:]? And then set the sort descriptors, or can i just skip the [request setEntity] and move straight to the sort descriptors and the  resultsArray? Also, am I setting the _outputLabel.text with an index from the resultsArray?

Comment: See my edit. I tend to use the first way to init simple fetchRequests but people seems to prefer the second way. For some requests, you will need the NSEntityDescription.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @user1966109 is exactly correct answer what you are looking for. Since you need to show the text in a label and for that you need to set predicate to get a single row. Set the predicate as below

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value == abc"];//considerin abc is the word you are looking for.
request.predicate = predicate;
//then execute the query.
```